# Find Primitive Root for Polynomial Field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

Can someone help me get started on the problem below:

Recall that $\mathbf{F}_{p^k}$ can be realized as $\mathbf{F}_p[x]/P(x)
  \cdot \mathbf{F}_p[x]$ where $P(x)$ is a polynomial of degree $k$ with
  coefficients in $\mathbf{F}_p$ which is irreducible.

**Problem** Find primitive roots for the fields $\mathbf{F}_8
  \cong \mathbf{F}_2[x]/(x^3+x+1) \cdot \mathbf{F}[x]$ (with elements $a+bx+cx^2$
  for $a,b,c \in \mathbf{F}_2$) and for $\mathbf{F}_9 \cong \mathbf{F}_3[x]/(x^2+1)$ (with
  elements $a+bx$ for $a,b \in \mathbf{F}_3$).  To do it, you just need to
  show that some polynomial has multiplicative order equal to $7$ in
  the first case and $8$ in the second case.

Comment: Try thinking of polynomials as their roots instead: Let $\xi\in\mathbb{F}_8$ such as $\xi^3+\xi+1=0$ so, $\xi^3=-\xi-1$ and try to "build up" $\mathbb{F}_8$ as $\xi,2\xi,3\xi,...,\xi+1,\xi+2,...\xi^2$ and their composites, noticing that $\xi^3=-\xi-1$ every time you meet $\xi^n$ for $n\ge 4$. It's not to hard to get these elements back to "polynomial" form.

Comment: Try $x$ as the polynomial in the first case. I think $x+1$ works in the second case.

Comment: Since $\mathbf{F}_8^\times$ has prime order $7$, then it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$.  What are the possible orders or elements? (There aren't many!)  Similarly, since $\# \mathbf{F}_9^\times = 8$, what are the possible orders?  If you find $\alpha \in \mathbf{F}_9^\times$, with $\alpha^4 \neq 1$, do you see that it must be a generator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the quotient $\mathbf{F}_8 \cong \mathbf{F}_2/(x^3+x+1)$ you have the relation
$$x^3+x+1=0 \iff x^3=-x-1=x+1,$$

since over $\mathbf{F}_2, -1=1$. You can use this relation to perform multiplications. In this case $\mathbf{F}_8^{\times} \cong \mathbf{Z}/7\mathbf{Z}$. By Lagrange the order of an element divides the order of the group, so it divides $7$, which is prime in $\mathbf{Z}$, therefore it is either $1$ or $7$, but the only element which has order $1$ is the unit $1$, so every other element has order $7$.

We can prove this directly, so that you get comfortable with how to use the relation above. Let us take $x \in \mathbf{F}_8$. (Again, you can take whatever element you like, so, if you want, just try it) We show that $\langle x \rangle =\mathbf{F}_8^{\times}$.

$x^1 = x;$

$x^2 =x^2;$

$x^3 = x+1;$

$x^4 = x\cdot x^3 = x(x+1)=x^2+x;$

$x^5 = x^2\cdot x^3 = x^2(x+1)=x^3+x^2=x+1+x^2;$

$x^6 = x^3\cdot x^3 = (x+1)^2 = x^2+2x+1=x^2+1,$ since over $\mathbf{F}_2, 2=0$;

$x^7 = x^6 \cdot x = (x^2+1)x = x^3+x = x+1+x=1.$

I let you do the other case. Just notice that the relation it holds this time is $x^2+1=0$...

If you have problems with it just ask :-).

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand. The other comments were correct, but too brief for me to understand. Quick q: What is the last term in the expression: $\mathbf{F}_8 \cong \mathbf{F}_2[x]/(x^3+x+1) \cdot \mathbf{F}[x]$

Comment: What polynomial yields order $8$ for $\mathbf{F}_9 \cong \mathbf{F}[x]/(x^2+1)$? Thank you!

Comment: @clay try with x+2