# Primitive element of finite field

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I am looking for primitive element of galois field of order $8.$ So, I can look at the field

$\mathbb{F}_8=\mathbb{Z}_2[x]/(x^3-x-1)$. I computed $\mathbb{F}_8^{\times}$ and now the primitive element is $a\in \mathbb{F}_8^{\times}$ such that $a^7=1$. Is there any easier way to find it without checking this property for all elements? Can this be generalized since the original question was for any finite field of order $8?$

Comment: $\mathbb{F}_8^\times$ is a group with $7$ elements. What do you know about groups of prime order?

Comment: @DanielFischer: Ah! I missed it. All it's elements are primitive elements

Comment: Except $1$, of course.

Comment: @DanielFischer Yes :) The question was extremely trivial. I apologize.

Comment: No need to apologise. And it's only trivial once you found the right point to look from.

Comment: Very similar to [this question.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1258567/find-primitive-root-for-polynomial-field#comment2556946_1258567)